# PHP JSON Encoding within foreach loop

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to generate the following JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "A1000",
        "name": "John Simpson",
        "serialID": "S41234",
        "tagID": "ABC6456"
    },  
    {
        "ID": "B2000",
        "name": "Sally Smith",
        "serialID": "B5134536",
        "tagID": "KJJ451345"
    },
    {
        "ID": "A9854",
        "name": "Henry Jones",
        "serialID": "KY4239582309",
        "tagID": "HYG452435"
    }
]
```

from within a PHP `foreach` loop which looks like this:

```
foreach($records as $record) {

        $ID = $record->getField('propertyID');
        $name = $record->getField('assignedName');
        $serialID = $record->getField('serial');
        $tagID = $record->getField('tag');

    }
```

I've tried using:

```
$arr = array('ID' => $ID, 'name' => $name, 'serialID' => $serialID, 'tagID' => $tagID);
```

which works for each record within the loop, but can't work out the syntax to join them together into a single JSON data string?

Comment: don't overwrite `$arr` each iteration, just add `[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Problem:-*** Your are over-writing your `$arr` variable each-time inside `foreach()` loop.That cause the issue.

***Solution:-*** Instead of over-writing, assign values to array like below:-

```
$arr = []; //create empty array

foreach($records as $record) {

    $arr[] = array(
                'ID' => $record->getField('propertyID');
                'name' => $record->getField('assignedName');
                'serialID' => $record->getField('serial');
                'tagID' => $record->getField('tag')
            );//assign each sub-array to the newly created array
} 
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add records to some kind of aggregation array and then `json_encode` it:

```
$items = [];
foreach($records as $record) {
    $items[] = [ 
        'ID' => $record->getField('propertyID'),
        'name' = $record->getField('assignedName'),
        'serialID' => $record->getField('serial'),
        'tagID' => $record->getField('tag'),
    ];
}

echo json_encode($items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data= array();
foreach($records as $record) {

$data[] = array(
        'ID' => $record->getField('propertyID');
        'name' => $record->getField('assignedName');
        'serialID' => $record->getField('serial');
        'tagID' => $record->getField('tag')
        );
    }

echo json_encode($data);
```

**Explanation:** Make an array, put all the values on one of their numerical index with in the loop, `json_enccode()` it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) for this:

```
$result = array_map(function ($record) {
    return [
        'ID'       => $record->getField('propertyID'),
        'name'     => $record->getField('assignedName'),
        'serialID' => $record->getField('serial'),
        'tagID'    => $record->getField('tag'),
    ];
}, $records);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ArrayName = array();

foreach($records as $record) {

        $ID = $record->getField('propertyID');
        $name = $record->getField('assignedName');
        $serialID = $record->getField('serial');
        $tagID = $record->getField('tag');

$ArrayName[] = array('ID' => $ID, 'name' => $name, 'serialID' => $serialID, 'tagID' => $tagID); //assign each sub-array to the newly created array

    }
echo json_encode($ArrayName);

?

> Blockquote
```

Answer (score -1):

this code will help you:

```
<?php
$resultArray = array();

foreach($records as $record) 
{
        $newResultArrayItem = array();
        $newResultArrayItem['ID'] = $record->getField('propertyID');
        $newResultArrayItem['name'] = $record->getField('assignedName');
        $newResultArrayItem['serialID'] = $record->getField('serial');
        $newResultArrayItem['tagID'] = $record->getField('tag');

        $resultArray[] = $newResultArrayItem;
}

$encodedArray = json_encode($ArrayName);

echo $encodedArray;

?>
```